# How Do I Have VSCode Detect and Import Methods From Libraries?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint

**I have this code:**

```
  const alarm = new cloudwatch.Alarm(this, 'Errors', {
    comparisonOperator: ComparisonOperator.GREATER_THAN_THRESHOLD,
    threshold: 1,
    evaluationPeriods: 1,
    metric: alias.metricErrors(),
  });
```

When I delete the "r" from `ComparisonOperator` and write it again, I would like VSCode to say, "do you want to import this from this library?".

Currently it does not underline `ComparisonOperator` saying it is not available, nor does it offer this feature of importing it for me.

**This is the popup I am looking for:**
[image: VS Code Popup]

**No red underlines (works in js):**
[image: VS Code No Red Underlines]

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "custom-resource",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "watch": "tsc -w",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-amplify/cli-extensibility-helper": "^2.0.0",
    "aws-cdk-lib": "^2.53.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^29.2.3",
    "@types/node": "^18.11.9",
    "@types/prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "esbuild": "^0.15.16",
    "jest": "^29.3.1",
    "ts-jest": "^29.0.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps to get results required:

1. Go to VS Code IDE
2. Type CTRL + SHIFT + P
3. Write "Preferences"
4. Click on "Preferences Open User Settings (JSON)"
5. Ensure the code below is present

**This is the code:**

```
{
  "[typescript]": {"editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"},
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "typescript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
  "typescript.format.semicolons": "ignore",
}
```

You'll need to (most likely) have ESLint and Prettier installed.